# Getting this black window instead of picture while using cv2.imshow

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, face-recognition

I don't know what term I should use for the window I am getting so I am attaching a screenshot of the window for reference.

[image: The ScreenShot of the window I m getting]

I am getting this window about 7 of the 10 times I am running this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition


imgElon = face_recognition.load_image_file("BasicFaceRecImg/ElonMusk2.jpg")
imgElon = cv2.cvtColor(imgElon, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
imgElon_face_loc = face_recognition.face_locations(imgElon)[0]
print(imgElon_face_loc)

imgElon_encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgElon)[0]
cv2.rectangle(imgElon, (imgElon_face_loc[0], imgElon_face_loc[3]), (imgElon_face_loc[1], imgElon_face_loc[2]),(255, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('Elon Musk', imgElon)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And the funny thing is that I am not getting this problem every time. It runs perfectly sometimes.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Have exactly the same problem. Annoying sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't with scripts that worked perfectly before. In my case, just before, it showed the error "Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"". I sudo installed this module again. Wonder if that's linked in any way.

Comment: The issue comes from Qt, see [this](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/362) and [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17827). You can build yourself the library to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help. You need to resize the image sometime the OpenCV messes with an image format this will work in all OpenCV versions hope this helps

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition

# cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
imgElon = face_recognition.load_image_file("elon.jpg")
print(type(imgElon.shape))
a,b,c=imgElon.shape


imgElon = cv2.cvtColor(imgElon, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
imgElon_face_loc = face_recognition.face_locations(imgElon)[0]
print(imgElon_face_loc)

imgElon_encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgElon)[0]
cv2.rectangle(imgElon, (imgElon_face_loc[0], imgElon_face_loc[3]), (imgElon_face_loc[1], imgElon_face_loc[2]),(255, 0, 255), 2)


imgElon=cv2.resize(imgElon, (a, b))

cv2.imshow('image', imgElon)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4):

I installed opencv-python-4.2.0.32 and the problem seems to have went away. I was using version 4.3.0.36 when having the issues.

Comment: Sajjad Aemmi you should mark this answer as the solution so it can benefit others and it marks this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was able to solve it using this code:

```
image = cv2.imread("./faces/test.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```