# Getting session management error while using cv2.imshow()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I was following a tutorial of OpenCV to show an image in a window.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
cv2.imshow('lena', img)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting this error.

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

please help me with this. I am new to ubuntu so I might need an in-depth explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because of a variable called SESSION_MANAGER. You need to unset it. Try this:

```
import cv2
unset SESSION_MANAGER
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
cv2.imshow('lena', img)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you work with PyCharm IDE, re-launch your program like this:

```
env -u SESSION_MANAGER pycharm-community
```

Comment: Thanks, Dennis Kozenikoff I tried both ways mentioned by you using ` unset SESSION_MANAGER` didn't work. However, relaunching the pycharm by the way you said worked fine. 
I need one more small help from you. Could you please answer to this question too?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62775458/11217252